# SwiftUI + CarPlay - audio player

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, carplay

So, we have the correct permissions to run our app on CarPlay - Apple approved. However they are talking about it being template based, and all we need to do is connect into the following commands.

```
MPPlayableContent
```

and the media nowplaying information - which is easy as we already do that through the approved method

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter and MPRemoteCommandCenter
```

So I am wondering what are the steps to do

```
MPPlayableContent
```

In SwiftUI. BTW we did not need the MFI to get these permissions as we are a radio station / Audio app.